# When a Button is enabled send the GPS data just when the Location changes

Tags: android, button, geolocation, gps, listener

I made two Buttons in my Android application.
the first one activates sending my GPS data to a Website.
the second one disables this option.
so my question is:

What can I do to make it possible that when my `activatebutton.isEnabled()==false` (already pushed) is,that each time when my location changes a method will be executed.

Answer (score 2):

Register a [LocationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) with an `onLocationChanged()` method using [`requestLocationUpdates`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener%29) when the enable is clicked, and remove it when the disable is clicked. Here's [an example](http://www.2linessoftware.com/2009/01/20/programming-with-android-part-3-building-wikiwhere/).

Comment: See my comment below.  Basically you need to ensure that you unregister the listener in the onPause and onStop and register it again in onResume.  If your app was destroyed it will automatically restart as your app starts it's main activity again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are requesting locationUpdates, don't forget to unregister the updates by overriding the onPause and onStop and re-registering in the onResume, otherwise it will be a huge battery drain.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html

Should cover everything you need to know.